# How to create a quick seach-as-you-type mechanism for a very large Core Data database?

Tags: iphone, database, search, core-data, nsdictionary

I am trying to implement a quick search as-you-type mechanism.

In my current implementation, when the user launches the app for the first time, he has to wait a little bit for a downloading process to complete. During that time, information about the 20,000 products that the app sells is being downloaded. Each product is represented by an instance of NSManagedObject and is added to a Core Data database.

The real problem is the way to use those products. After the user launches the app once again (not the first time), the products need to be loaded to memory so the search would be quick.
In order to do that, I loop over the entire database and create an instance of NSDictionary for each product that contains its information, because it is much easier to use dictionary objects in my program to retrieve information about the product.

Because the dictionaries are stored in the memory and therefore the search process is very quick, but iterating over the 20,000 objects (onces per launch) and creating dictionaries takes a lot of time (about a minute), so that solution is not good.

I thought about another way to reach the quick-search goal: Fetching objects from the database after each letter has been typed. But I do not know how fast it would be.

What is the recommended way to do that?

Thanks,
Sagiftw

Comment: how is the search done? Is it a text search matching by product name?

Comment: The search is done using NSPredicate. The search is coMplex: except from searching if the searched text matches the product's name, I'm also checking if the searched text matches the product's manufacturer, or if it contains info about the product's size, amount, price and etc.

Comment: Did you consider using an additional string attribute on your searchable entity which contains the matching keywords? That would let you query just on that atribute for matches, rather than on many indexed fields. You could populate that attribute when seeding the data.

Comment: Also, querying Unicode texts is time-consuming in Core Data, so if you use an additional attribute holding the searchable keywords, make sure those are normalized. Example here: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/ipad/#samplecode/DerivedProperty/Introduction/Intro.html

Answer (score 2):

I have a similar feature in my app but have considerable less records. I have indices on all search fields and create as simple (inexpensive) sql querys (NSPredicate)as possible from the input (2nd fetchedResultsController only for searching). The result set contains the 'search items'. This is at least fast enough for around 1000 entries (test data size) with a random distribution of text type search keys. Its possible a good idea to fetch in the background to prevent the gui from being unresponsive.

Comment: It's a good idea to fetch in the background, but I'm not sure how fast it would be with 20k items database.